# bcchanger.com: why are bitcoins being sold at 1/3 market value?

Tags: exchanges, market

Why are bitcoins being sold at 1/3 market value at [bcchanger.com](http://bcchanger.com/bitcoin-sell-orders)?

Are the lowball sellers trying to scam people or throw away money?

Comment: I'm puzzled. They accept PayPal money, so if they try to scam you, you could reverse the transaction AFAIK...

Comment: yep!  Thanks for fixing the question, too.  :-)

Comment: Looks like at least some people are getting scammed at this site, see:  http://forums.bcchanger.com/topic/26/dog420-is-scamming-a-lot-of-people/

Comment: Every time i try to buy bitcoin's on that site nothing happens i don't get any bitcoin's and i never hear from the seller, lucky i haven't been scammed yet.

Comment: bcchanger doesn't sell coins at their own, they are just acting as a mediator where seller and buyers meet each other. Needles to say, spam rate is very high.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at low price orders posting date, you will notice most of them are relatively older OR with zero feedback. The ones that with some positive feedbacks are genearlly in line with the price of the order posting date.

So it is more of a combination of old orders and scams.

Comment: Still, how can you try to scam someone if you are to be payed by paypal? They can reverse the transaction, can't they?

Comment: @Lohoris They can reverse the transaction if they're willing to risk being banned for life by PayPal.